# How to loop through double pointers without knowing size. (C)

Tags: c, pointers

How can I loop through this double pointer without knowing it's size.

```c
char *arr[] = {"ant", "bat", "cat", "dog", "egg", "fly"}; 
char **ptr = arr; // Double pointer
```

I tried this but I get an error

```c
while (*ptr){
   printf("%s\n",*ptr);
   ptr+=1;
}
```

I wan't something similar to this but with double pointers.

```c
char *word = *ptr;
for (int i = 0; *(word + i) != '\0'; i++)
{
   printf("%c", *(word + i));
}
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: 16711 Segmentation fault: 11  ./Main

Comment: By using a sentinel value? For example `char *arr[] = {"ant", "bat", "cat", NULL};`

Comment: Well, you do while (*ptr), but there’s no zero in your list.  Try adding a NULL.

Comment: With a `for` loop. `for(size_t i=0; i < sizeof arr / sizeof arr[0]; i++)`

Comment: @WeatherVaneis exactly right. C strings (`char *`) use the sentinel value `'\0'`.

Comment: @Chris that's quite different. This is a `NULL` pointer value. It is used as a sentinel *instead* of a pointer to a string literal.

Comment: Generally, it's preferable to store the size of the array instead of using a sentinel. You do know the array size in this case, so just use it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason you can determine the end of a string with `\0` is because when you assign one to a pointer a null byte is automatically placed at the end, note that the definition of string is a null terminated array of characters. You can mimic this behavior in an array of strings by adding a NULL element at the end:

```
char *arr[] = {"ant", "bat", "cat", "dog", "egg", "fly", NULL};
char **ptr = arr;  // Double pointer

while (*ptr) {
    printf("%s\n", *ptr);
    ptr += 1;
}
```

This is what is called a sentinel.

Comment: Would this work regardless of the type of the array ints etc ..

Comment: For other data types will only work if the sentinel value cannot be a data value. For example using `INT_MIN` as the sentinel, when that value never occurs in the data itself. It works here because `NULL` can never be the address of a string.

Comment: Tip: You can use `NAN` as a sentinel value for an array of floating point numbers.